# How can I get my directive to run after and operate on ng-bind-html content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Suppose I want to make a directive called `addHello` that adds the element `<span>hello!</span>` to the following paragraph `<p><span>I say</span> </p>`. Here's a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/n54TfFUTg9OEwUPboHUg?p=preview):

HTML

```
<p ng-bind-html="whatIsay" addHello></p>
```

AngularJS

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.whatIsay = $sce.trustAsHtml('<span>I say </span>')
})

app.directive('addHello', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.append(angular.element('<span>hello!</span>'))
    }
  }
})
```

The end result should be `<p><span>I say</span> <span>hello!</span></p>`

Basically, I want `ng-bind-html` to do its work, then I want my directive `addHello` to run after it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the `$timeout` hack, you can do away with `ng-bind-html` and add a parameter to your directive, like so:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <p add-hello="whatIsay"></p>
</body>
```

And here's the directive code:

```
app.directive('addHello', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            trustedHtml: "=addHello",
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.append("<p>hello</p>" + scope.trustedHtml.toString() + "<p>goodbye</p>");               
        }
    };
});
```

And here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NdyfOpMe3vxTncDPw6mO?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, but if you do a $timeout call in the directive's linking function you'll get the desired effect. [see the plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4OjnwFVmxw0PHxLKidrY?p=preview)

```
link: function(scope, element) {
  $timeout(function () {
    element.append(angular.element('<span>hello!</span>'))  
  }, 0);
}
```

I don't think priority work's here, because the element hasn't been updated yet? Maybe someone knows better.